# How do I make an automatic image slideshow that I can pause and press next and backwards?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried combining the codes from W3 School for their example 1 and auto play slideshow.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

Upon trying, my slide show jumps around madly and the next button does not work anymore.
I also want to include a function to be able to pause the image whenever I want.

This is my code from W3 school so far:

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000);

}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="image1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Codes</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="image2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">What I have learnt</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="image3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">CSS Style</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
```

How do I make it so:
1.I have a play/pause function
2.Images play for 5 seconds on auto play
3.Clicking left and right is able to go to previous or next image

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I think there are a lot of libs that handle it very well if you using jQuery then use `Slik or Owl`, or if want to add the only javascript then `Flickity` is a great option. Own custom code has a lot of device compatibility issues and not a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap to implement this carousel more more easier
check this link out for more info: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/

Answer (score 0):

This will work,

```
 <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/09/14/18/04/dandelion-445228__340.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Codes</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://cdn.cjr.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/AdobeStock_100000042-e1563305717660-686x371.jpeg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">What I have learnt</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://static-cse.canva.com/blob/142356/removing-background-images_Unsplash.bad043c2.jpeg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">CSS Style</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="toggleSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="toggleSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="showSlides(1,true)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="showSlides(2,true))"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="showSlides(3,true))"></span> 
</div>

<script>
var doAnimation = true;
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function toggleSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex + n, true);
}
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides")).forEach((mySlide)=> {
  mySlide.addEventListener("mouseover",function() {
    doAnimation = false;
  })
  mySlide.addEventListener("mouseout",function() {
    doAnimation = true;
  });
});
var timer;
function showSlides(n, force) {
  console.log(doAnimation)
  if (doAnimation || force) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (n) {
      slideIndex = n;
    }
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    if (force) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      timer = setInterval(showSlides, 5000);
    }
  }
}
timer = setInterval(showSlides, 5000);
</script>

</body>
```